# Pointer for the first struct member list in nasm assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

How can i declare a pointer for the first element in a list of a struct like this:

```
section .bss
struc agenda
     name   resb 10
     number resd 10
     type   resw 10
endstruc
```

Comment: The nasm manual is ambiguous about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply declaring the structure does not reserve memory for it. You need an instance of it. Either:

```
section .bss
    my_agenda resb agenda_size
; or perhaps...
    agenda_array resb agenda_size * MAX_COUNT
; or...
section .data
    an_agenda istruc agenda
    at name db "fred"
    at number db "42"
    at type db "regular"
    iend
section .text
    mov esi, an_agenda
    mov al, [esi + name]
```

Something like that?

Heh! Jester has just posted essentially the same thing. He introduces the '.' notation for local labels. Probably a good idea. Without it, `name` is a global identifier and can't be reused. It takes slightly more typing - `agenda.name`, `agenda.number`, `agenda.type`. Probably worth it for increased clarity.

Comment: Frank... This is ok! Thanks for the response, but what i don't understand is if i have different sizes inside the structure like, resb, resw, resd... And the structure is offside of bss and data section?

Comment: Different sizes are no problem. It's what `struc` is "for" essentially. I don't understand "offside of bss and data". The `struc` macro (yeah, it's a macro) itself is just a "typedef". To have a pointer to it, you've gotta have one - in .bss or .data or perhaps in newly allocated memory.

Answer (score 5):

As usual, you should have consulted the fine [nasm manual](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.02/html/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.12.10) before asking. It's not too late to do that now, but I'll quickly give you the important points from there.

`struc` itself doesn't allocate a structure, it defines a type. As recommended practice, you should name your fields starting with a dot (`.`). Each field label will be equal to its offset in the structure, though a base address can also be added. Having declared your struct, you can allocate initialized instances with the `istruc` directive. In the `.bss` section, you'd want to use `resb` instead, using the `struc_size` symbol that the assembler defines for you.

A complete example which declares the type, defines a zero-initialized instance in the bss section and loads the address of the first member may look like this:

```
struc agenda
     .name   resb 10
     .number resb 10
     .type   resb 10
endstruc

section .bss

myagenda: resb agenda_size

section .text
    mov eax, myagenda + agenda.name
```

Note: `agenda.name` is of course `0`, I have written it out just as an illustration how you'd do it for other members.

Comment: Sorry, but i forget to edit my question... In this case it's ok, but if i change the size of the addresses like i have edited with resd, resw or resb??

Comment: ahhh, that's because i thought that are incompatible sizes between the declaration of myagenda: resb agenda_size and the typedefs like resb, resd, resw... thanks for the response!